# PHP Implode But Wrap Each Element In Quotes

Tags: php, implode

Assume I have an array:

```
 $elements = array('foo', 'bar', 'tar', 'dar');
```

Then I want to build up a `DELETE IN` SQL query:

```
 $SQL = "DELETE FROM elements
               WHERE id IN ('" . implode(',', $elements) . "')";
```

The problem is that the ids in the elements array aren't quoted each individually. I.E the query looks like:

```
 $SQL = "DELETE FROM elements
               WHERE id IN ('foo,bar,tar,dar');
```

What's the best, most elegants way to fix this?

Comment: Be very careful... you are likely open to some serious SQL injection.

Comment: What's the best way to prevent against SQL injection with the solution provided by `nickb` then? Thanks.

Answer (score 139, accepted):

Add the quotes into the `implode` call: (I'm assuming you meant `implode`)

```
$SQL = 'DELETE FROM elements
           WHERE id IN ("' . implode('", "', $elements) . '")';
```

This produces:

```
DELETE FROM elements WHERE id IN ("foo", "bar", "tar", "dar")
```

The best way to prevent against SQL injection is to make sure your elements are properly escaped.

An easy thing to do that should work (but I haven't tested it) is to use either `array_map` or `array_walk`, and escape every parameter, like so:

```
$elements = array();
$elements = array_map( 'mysql_real_escape_string', $elements);
```

Comment: Perfect, so what's the best way to prevent against SQL injection as Brad suggested with this solution?

Comment: @Jusin I've edited my answer with a suggestion on preventing SQL injection.

Comment: @Justin The best way is to use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Don't use mysql_ functions.

Answer (score 19):

You can use [**`array_walk`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) to iterate all the elements in side the array passing the reference to the element and add the quotes in the following way.

**php 7.4 or newer**

```
<?php

$arr = ['a','b','c'];

array_walk($arr, fn(&$x) => $x = "'$x'");

echo implode(',', $arr); // 'a','b','c'
```

**php 7.3 or older version**

```
<?php

$arr = ['a','b','c'];

array_walk($arr, function(&$x) {$x = "'$x'";});

echo implode(',', $arr); // 'a','b','c'
```

Comment: Please add clarification as to why this is an answer. It may seem trivial to you, but since you do not add any explanation your suggestion is open to interpretation about its use.

Comment: The link is the "clarification"

Answer (score 4):

You can run a simple array_map() function to wrap the strings in quotes and then wrap that around the implode() to add the commas:

```
$array = ["one", "two", "three", "four"];

implode(",", array_map(function($string) {
    return '"' . $string . '"';
}, $array));
```

Answer (score 4):

How about json_encode?

```
$arr=array("foo","bar","tar","dar");
$str=json_encode($arr);
echo $str;
```

Result:
["foo","bar","tar","dar"]

Comment: This is the best answer.

Comment: This is the best answer by far! Short and fast! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this as well

```
$elements = array('foo', 'bar', 'tar', 'dar');

$data = '"' . implode('", "', $elements) . '"';

echo $data; // "foo", "bar", "tar", "dar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the top answer a bit here, even if you are using MySQLi it is possible to call real_escape_string using array_map by using the object method `callable` form. Here is an example, assuming `$conn` is your MySQLi connection:

```
$elements = array('foo', 'bar', 'tar', 'dar');
$cleanedElements = array_map([$conn, 'real_escape_string'], $ids);
$SQL = 'DELETE FROM elements WHERE id IN ("' . implode('", "', $elements) . '")';
```

Note that the first parameter of array_map is an array with the object followed by the method name. This is the same as executing the following for each item in the array:

```
$newItem = $conn->real_escape_string($item);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just want to note that the top answer won't fully work. You will have a missing element at the end of your implode.

So instead of:

```
DELETE FROM elements WHERE id IN ("foo", "bar", "tar", "dar")
```

You will get:

```
DELETE FROM elements WHERE id IN ("foo", "bar", "tar", "dar)
```

Notice that the end element "dar is now missing a quote.